# How to format long POST body string with Ansible URI Module?

Tags: ansible, yaml, uri, ansible-2.x

I need to issue a lot of POST requests as part of the Ansible playbook I'm putting together.  I'm using the uri module and need to send the data in the x-www-form-urlencoded format with the key/value pairs as shown from the example Ansible documentation below:

```
- uri:
    url: https://your.form.based.auth.example.com/index.php
    method: POST
    body: "name=your_username&password=your_password&enter=Sign%20in"
    status_code: 302
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  register: login
```

My problem is that my body strings are very long, some with 20+ parameters as one large run-on line.  I'd like to be able to specify the parameters as a list such as:

```
body: 
  name: your_username
  password: your_password
  enter: SignIn
  ...
```

And have the result automatically sent in the same format (x-www-form-urlencoded, not JSON).  Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can write the body as JSON. See `body_format` in http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/uri_module.html

Comment: The problem with that seems to be that the server will not accept a JSON formatted body in the POST.  It requires the body is formatted as x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood the documentation, sorry

Comment: **See also:** YAML folded string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YAML, you can use newlines and backslashes to ignore them in a doublequoted string:

```
body: "param1=value1&\
  param2=value2&\
  param3=value3"
```

Normally, the newlines will be turned into spaces, but the backslash prevents that, and the lines will be joined together without spaces.

Edit:
Another way would be to store a variable before and than use a jinja2 filter:

```
vars:
  query:
    - param1=value1
    - param2=value2
    - param3=value3
...
  body: "{{ query | join('&') }}"
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution if the YAML style syntax isn't currently possible.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3685908 I added an alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`form-urlencoded` body format](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-body_format) to avoid having to set the content type and encode the body by yourself.

```yaml
- uri:
    url: https://your.form.based.auth.example.com/index.php
    method: POST
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    body: 
      name: your_username
      password: your_password
      enter: SignIn
    status_code: 302
  register: login
```